# Enable the status code 206 for Apache Tomcat 6

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat6

I want to play some mp4 and webm video files from my webapp Folder by the HTML5 video tag.

But I have the problem that the status code with the tomcat is only 200:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/resources/1.mp4
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

But when I do the same from a apache webserver I will get the status-code 206:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/1.mp4
Request Method:GET
Status Code:206 Partial Content
```

Is it possible to activate the code 206 for the apache tomcat. By default in the web.xml the useAcceptRanges is [true].

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement HTTP range support yourself. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325345/serving-audio-data-from-a-java-servlet-for-an-html5-audio-control), nearly identical question/answer.