# Serving up an audio (mp3) file from a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, spark-java

So I'm serving up an mp3 file using `HttpServletResponse` writing to a servlet output stream.

When I go to that location in the browser, the mp3 correctly loads up and starts playing, but unfortunately, isn't able to seek anywhere(I can't scroll through the song at all)

How do I fix this, or make it so the browser downloads the full song before it starts playing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it in an audio controls tag, assuming HTML5. See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp for an example. Just replace the hardcoded mp3 with a call to your servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You servlet must be able to respond to HTTP range requests, i.e. serve not the whole mp3 from start, but also subparts.

Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325345/serving-audio-data-from-a-java-servlet-for-an-html5-audio-control) for further information. It links to [page](http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html) which shows how to implement support for http range and other important headers.

**EDIT:** corrected URL

Comment: That seems to only be information about client-side. Does that mean that my servlet is working correctly, and going to that URL shouldn't allow seeking?

Comment: sorry, wrong URL, edited and entered a different. But just google "http range" for lots of information.